# Embed app.config into Assembly

Tags: .net, app-config, embedded-resource, fody-costura

Is there any existing solution to embed the app.config file into the resulting assembly?
I know there's [costura](http://code.google.com/p/costura/) for embedding DLL's into the assembly (costura also provides a really nice VS plugin!)

**Some equalient project for the app.config?**

Comment: Then it is no longer configuration...

Comment: It is! I want my WCF config in the file, but I also want no one to change the config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not really config if you are not allowed to configure it.  Why dont you set these things in code instead?  That way only a dev can change them and there is no need for a config file?

Comment: Cause I am lazy and I don't want to transform my complete WCF config with custom bindings etc. into code config.

Comment: lol, an honest admission there! There may be a way to get round this issue but the problem you are hitting is that the .net default behaviour is to have the .config file separate so it CAN be configured.  Its like providing a UI to configure your system and then making all the fields read-only!

Comment: But even the UI would be useful, cause you could see the default config, and that's exaclty what I want!